# How Do I Set Default Launch Folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I want VSCode to always open the same folder when I launch it. The current behavior is to launch whatever folder VSCode thinks I last visited.

I maintain notes that are kept in folders on the same system that I run my local VSCode instance from. All of my development is on remote systems that are often not running when I launch VM. In a development session, I often have many (5-10) files open in VSCode on various source, config, and data files -- often on multiple remote systems. These remote systems are frequently not even running when I next launch VSCode.

When I launch VSCode, I want VSCode to always open (from the desktop) my local "notes" folder, where I keep my daily journal files. I want to then open folders on remote systems -- most often using the "File -> Open Recent" command.

I do not see anything in `settings.json` or in preferences that lets me control what folder is open on startup.

How do I configure VSCode so that it always opens the same (local) folder on startup, regardless of what files I was editing when I last closed it?

Comment: start VSC with a command line argument of the folder you want to open

Comment: @rioV8: I encourage you to add an "answer" with more specifics. I launch VSC from a shortcut on my (local) Windows10 Pro desktop. That desktop is running on a guest VM running Windows 10 Pro in a VirtualBox hypervisor. ALL the resources it uses are "remote", in that the remote-ssh extension is used to access them. If you have the time, please offer an example of how to add the needed arguments to the shortcut used to launch VSC.